# How to match exact pattern using `str_count`

Tags: r, stringr

I'm having trouble using `str_count`. Say, I've got a vector such as this:

```
x <- "§df §d §a"
```

and I want to count how often the pattern `§d` as a wordlike substring occurs. The result of this is incorrect:

```
str_count(x, "§d")
[1] 2
```

The expected result is `1`.

Wrapping word boundaries around the pattern is no help either:

```
str_count(x, "\\b§d\\b")
[1] 0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: No, in the real data there can also be a comma

Comment: did you try this: str_count(x, " \\§d\\ ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word boundaries won't work here - word characters are numbers, letters, and underscores, and word boundaries are defined as a non-word character next to a word character. Since `§` isn't a word character,  `§` is just two non-word characters, not a word boundary.

For your example, you can still use a word boundary after the `d` and get the expected result:

```
str_count(x, "§d\\b")
# [1] 1
```

If there is a possibility of other characters before the § and you want to prevent matches in those cases, then I think your best bet is negative lookbehind, make sure it is not preceded by anything other than a space:

```
str_count(x, "(?<![\\S])§d\\b")
[1] 1
```